# Confusion with change of (multiple) variables theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem: Calculate I

$$Q = \{x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x+y > 0, y+z>0, x+z > 0\}$$

$$I =\int_{Q}e^{-x-y-z}dV$$

My attempt:

$$\psi(x,y,z) = (x+y, y+z, x+z)$$

The change of variables theorem states that (for suitable psi, Q)

$$\int_{\psi(Q)}f(x)dx = \int_{Q} f(\psi(y)) \ det(D(\psi)(y)) dy\tag{1}$$

Equivalently

$$\int_{\psi \psi^{⁻1}Q}f(x)dx = \int_{\psi^{-1}Q} f(\psi(y)) \ det(D(\psi)(y)) dy$$

So...
$$I =\int_{Q}e^{-x-y-z}dxdydz = 2\int_{\mathbb{R_+}^3}e^{-2u-2v-2w}dudvdw = \frac{1}{4}\tag{2}$$

However the correct answer is $4$. What is wrong with my reasoning here?

I get the correct answer when instead I use

$$\int_{Q}f(x)dx = \int_{\psi^{-1}Q} f(\psi^{-1}(y)) \ det(D(\psi^{-1})(y)) dy$$

But i'm confused how that follows from the original equation. Am i interpreting it wrong somehow?

Comment: $u+v+w=2(x+y+z)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do interpret it wrongly, most likely as a result of conflicting notations ($\psi$ and $Q$ that you define are not the same as in the formula). Let's look at the formula (1). Here $x$ is the old variable, $y$ is the new variable and $x=\psi(y)$ is the variable substitution that transforms *new* variable to the *old* one. The original set in terms of $x$ is $\psi(Q)$, and $Q$ is the integration set in terms of $y$, i.e. the new variable.

When you apply it to your case, you define $\psi$ that transforms old variables to the new one, that is it should, in fact, be $\psi^{-1}$. Thus, the determinant in (2) should be $\frac12$. Moreover, you get it wrong in (2) (see my comment above). It should be $x+y+z=\frac12(u+v+w)$.

Your last edit looks much better.